# Advertising blocker in javascript

Tags: javascript, adsense, ads, adblock

I am working on an ad blocker coded in javascript. I have some code from an old project, what I do so far is to loop on all the iframes and I search if the src url match a list like:

```
/http:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]*mediaplex\.com/,
/http:\/\/ad\.yieldmanager\.com/,
/http:\/\/ad\.zanox\.com/,
```

Is this a good way to do it or will I miss too many ads that doesnt work this way?

Also is there something like this already made so I can check that code? I was checking a few firefox extensions like ad_blocker-0.6 and adblock_plus-1.2.2 but they are different from what I want to do, they mostly have "event listeners", I need to work with the already displayed code and I use pure js without any lib or framework. I get the iframes using DOM.

Comment: AdBlock(+) use the event listeners because some advertisers do this: `<script>document.write('<iframe src="http://www.spamvertiser.com/steal_your_dataz.html">');</script>`

Comment: But since I am reading the page code with DOM, wouldn't I catch those too?

Comment: I suppose that would depend on when you're running your function. Some ad scripts I've seen will write a new ad to the page after a period of time has gone by.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to simplify the ad blocker. Here are some classic solutions:

- [Floopymoose Ad Blocker](http://www.floppymoose.com/)
- [Gozer Ad Blocker](http://www.gozer.org/mozilla/ad_blocking/)
- [FlashBlock](http://flashblock.mozdev.org/index.html)